# prove $A \sim B\implies 2^A \sim 2^B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to prove that if $A \sim B$ then $2^A \sim 2^B$.

$A\sim B$: There is a bijection from $A$ to $B$

thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question, by $2^{A}$ do you mean the set of all subsets of $A$?

Comment: yes, that how I understand that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $f:A\to B$ is a bijection, and consider the map

$$F:2^A\to 2^B:X\mapsto f[X]=\{f(a):a\in X\}\;.$$

Comment: thanks, it helped... too bad I can't even "vote up" for you :(

Comment: @Hades200621: That’s okay; the most important thing is that it did help!